# How to check if any column value has changed in pdo update query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to check if any column value has changed while updating the record using PDO. I am explaining my query below.

```
$qry ="UPDATE cb_driver_info 
       SET owner_id=:owner_id,
           email=:email,
           mobile=:mobile,
           image=:image 
       WHERE id=:driver_id";
$stmt = $db->prepare($qry);
$stmt->bindParam(':owner_id', htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($owner_id)));
$stmt->bindParam(':email', htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($email)));
$stmt->bindParam(':mobile', htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($mobile)));
$stmt->bindParam(':image', htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($image)));
$stmt->bindParam(':driver_id', htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($driver_id)));
$stmt->execute();
```

Here I am updating the record. I need to check if any column value has chaged while updating then it will `return 1` and if same record is updating again it will `return 0`.

Comment: Why do you have this (unusual) requirement?

Comment: It's probably not wise to use `htmlspecialchars()` on *input* into the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`rowCount()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php). If any row is affected by an update (i.e. any column value has changed) this will count 1 for that row. From the MySQL [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html):

> If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this and does not update it. 
>   UPDATE returns the number of rows that were actually changed.

After your `$stmt->execute()` use

```
if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
    // some rows changed
    // do something
}
```

If you just want to return a true/false value if an update occurred, you can either

```
return $stmt->rowCount() > 0;
```

or if you're not using strict type matching (i.e. `===`), simply

```
return $stmt->rowCount();
```

Comment: Its always returns 1 no mater the column value has changed or not.

Comment: @subhra are you sure you're not changing any data? it works fine for me...

Answer (score 1):

From a comment in the [manual of `rowCount()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php),

> When updating a Mysql table with identical values nothing's really affected so rowCount will return 0.

This is not explicitly documented in the PHP manual of [`rowCount()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php). It is, however, documented in the [MySQL `UPDATE` documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html),

> If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this and does not update it.

combined with

> UPDATE returns the number of rows that were actually changed.

However, beware that this behavior is changed if you add the `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true` option when defining your PDO object. With that option, it will return the number of rows affected, regardless if their values were in fact updated (so it will return 1 even if the values didn't change, so long as it found records matching your `WHERE` condition).

So your code would end up being

```
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->rowCount() ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: The `rowCount` behaviour is documented under `UPDATE` in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html): "If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this and does not update it. " and "UPDATE returns the number of rows that were actually changed"

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more *explicit* and said that it isn't explicitly documented in the documentation of the method `rowCount()`.. ;-) You're absolutely right, the MySQL docs specifies it.

Comment: Don't mind me I can be a bit pedantic at times... :-)